# preg_match gives compilation failed error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm a total regex noob but I have a problem I need to figure out.

I have a text file with the following...

```
String 1
Some variable
String 2
```

I've had a look and thought I was on a winner with this but I get an error

```
preg_match( '/(String 1)(?:[^])*(String 2)/', $string, $matches );
```

but I get this error

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 33

Can anyone help me to figure it out please?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `(?:[^])*` is supposed to be doing in your regex?

Comment: @anubhava: `[^]` is valid in JavaScript - perhaps someone tried to port the regex without using the proper tool for the job ([RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com))...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you think `(?:[^])*` matches any character "zero or more" times.

In Javascript, `[^]` represents a valid character class which matches any character. This does not work the same for PCRE, it compiles as an incomplete character class. Use the dot `.` instead combined with the `s` (dotall) modifier.

```
preg_match('/(String 1).*?(String 2)/s', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: That's not my concern, OP did not explain what he/she was doing. I'm just pointing out the error.

Comment: Very true. I seemed to have "jumped the gun" and assumed.

Comment: Although I'm sure there is something that would do the job better, this worked perfectly for what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps simplify it and make it just;

```
/^(String 1|String 2)$/m
```

For example;

```
<?php

$s = <<<STR
String 1
Some variable
String 2
STR;

$output_array = array();
preg_match("/^(String 1|String 2)$/m", $s, $output_array);

echo print_r($output_array, true);
```

#### [***Live Preview***](https://eval.in/196874)

- `^` - Match the beginning of the line/string
- `(..)` - Our capture group
- `$` - Match the end of the line/string

Comment: @M42 Yeah. I (mistakenly) assumed OP wanted to only match `String 1` and `String 2`.